How to navigate to Home Controller regardless of which controller is initiated from the URL?
Our website currently doesn't have do not have authentication, Authorization and Login page and it is designed to direct users to the Home Controller and Welcome Action Method. Upon accessing the Home Controller, we will initialize several settings and load the cache to facilitate subsequent navigation.
However, there are instances when users directly access other Controllers, such as User Management and Approvals, via the URL, bypassing the Home Controller. This action does not trigger the initialization of the essential settings.
Is there a method to redirect the URL to the Home Page (Home Controller) when users attempt to access the User Management or Approvals controllers?
Since we do not have authentication and Authorization (Login page), we have more then 20 views, we just need a better way to handle our case.
Route in Program.cs
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Welcome}/{id?}");


Thanks in advance!!!
For First time, We need to navigate to home controller regardless of what was launched in URL.

Do you mean you want to redirect to the HomeController regardless which url/action users are trying to access for initialization? And then, can we say, if the intialization had been done, then we don't need to redirect to HomeController when users are visiting other pages? If so, I think we can define an action filter to check whether the initialization task is completed, if not, redirect to HomeController, may I know whether there's a flag or mark can be used to check the initialization task?

Could you please provide more information about the conditions upon which you want to redirect your users to the welcome page? I can image you don't want to send existing users to welcome page every time they come back. There are several ways to do this and some are better depending on what you need to initialize and what conditions are in play. Additionally, even if you don't use auth, you can go ahead and study the source code of how it is done - it uses general facilities that you can use too, just based on your conditions and requirements.

When we launch page for first time, it should be navigated to Home Screen. Sometimes users are launching other page(controller) directly, which makes to skip initialize the configuration

Yes but what exactly do you mean by "first time"? First visit of a specific user? First visit from a specific browser (e.g. based on a cookie?) First visit during a session? First visit in a specific time period? EDIT: Anyway, the global filter solution provided in the answer will probably work for you if you manage to flesh out the decision-making logic.

in First visit, we will download all dropdown values with ajax call and save it in local, it will be picked up by UI upon the navigation,

May I know whether there's any other concerns about the action filter?

If you're fetching various semi-static information (dropdowns, ...) on first load, isn't the UI the place to do this? As in the UI knows whether it has the data to display the current page. Can't you ajax-load the data regardless of what page you land on via a common boostrap script shared in all pages?

We can create a filter in MVC application to control whether the app is going to redirect to HomeController. Here's the related document for action filter. Don't forget to register the filter globally.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
     options.Filters.Add<GlobalSampleActionFilter>();
});

public class SampleActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var controllerName = context.RouteData.Values["controller"]?.ToString();
        var actionName = context.RouteData.Values["action"]?.ToString();
        //your logic to check whether initialization task's completed or not
        bool initIsCompleted = false;
        // Check if the current endpoint is going to hit User management page or Approvals page
        // also check whether the initialization task is completed
        // if yes, then redirect to Home Page.
        if (controllerName?.ToLower() == "UserManagement" && actionName?.ToLower() == "index" && !initIsCompleted)
        {
            context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("Index", "Home", null);
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // Do something after the action executes.
    }
}


Thank you for your kind reponse, feel free to let me know if my codes doesn't  work for you.
